# Make EJB 3.1 bindings default to interface and not class name

Tags: java, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

```
@Singleton
public class DummySentenceManager implements SentenceManager {
```

binds to

```
[java:global/appname/mypkg.DummySentenceManager, java:global/appname/mypkg.DummySentenceManager!mypkg.SentenceManager]
```

I would like it to bind to:

```
[java:global/appname/mypkg.SentenceManager]
```

without resorting to:

```
@Singleton(name="mypkg.SentenceManager")
public class DummySentenceManager implements SentenceManager {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like it to bind like that?  The EJB must be unique within the module name anyway, so there's no reason to qualify the name with a package.  Also, the whole point of `java:global` bindings is that they aren't customizable in this way: they follow a strict and predictable pattern.

(For what it's worth, `.` is not a valid name for an ejb-name when specified in XML, per the XSD.  I wouldn't be surprised if you hit problems in EJB implementations due to this.)

Comment: If I don't do that, how do I do a JNDI lookup for any EJB that implements the SentenceManager interface?

Comment: There is no standard mechanism for looking up EJBs by interface only.  If you define an `@EJB(name="java:app/ejb/mypkg.ServiceManager", beanInterface=mypkg.ServiceManager.class)` somewhere in your application, then you could use `new InitialContext().lookup("java:app/ejb/mypkg.ServiceManager")`.